# How can I delete rows that have text after a specific substring?

Tags: sql, database, pyspark, databricks

I'm faced with a database right now and the information in the rows *normally* follow a specific sequence:

1. Four digit ID - usually IE01
2. System ID  - 5 characters
3. Main ID - 5 character string following a prefix - either "I0", "N0" or "Q0"
4. Tag number - 3-5 character string

A typical row would look like "IE01-236613-I073619-F021". The tag is F021, but there could be a hundred other tags also.

What I want though, is to only keep the rows that contain no tag whatsoever.

In the row example, I want to remove the "F021" so it looks like "IE01-2313-IO73619".

Some rows might not follow that structure, but what they *all* have in common is a main ID prefix with 5 characters.

If I could, at a high level:

1. Look for a main ID prefix (either "I0", "N0" or "Q0")
2. Count 5 characters ahead
3. Delete rows that contain anything after that.

What I've tried is to query rows that contain JUST the main ID (with the 5 chars) but that only selects and once I did it., I realised it wasn't what I needed. I can't figure out how to include all the info, right up to where the 5 characters in the main ID ends.

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN t.field1 LIKE '%-I0%' THEN SUBSTRING(t.field1, CHARINDEX('I0', t.field1) + LEN('I0'), 5)
    WHEN t.field1 LIKE '%-N0%' THEN SUBSTRING(t.field1, CHARINDEX('N0', t.field1) + LEN('N0'), 5)
    WHEN t.field1 LIKE '%-Q0%' THEN SUBSTRING(t.field1, CHARINDEX('Q0', t.field1) + LEN('Q0'), 5)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS next_five_chars
FROM table1 t
```

That just returns, in the above example, `73619`. I want the very start of the row, right up to the end of `73619`.

I've been racking my brain and can't seem to figure it out. I bet it's something really obvious!

Comment: how do the no tag rows look like? `"IE01-236613-I073619-"` or `"IE01-236613-I073619"`?

Comment: The latter :) The dashes are the delimiters!

Comment: would `-` be the delimiter for all rows? if so, we can split the string by `-` delimiter and count the number of elements after the split. 4 elements = has a tag. 3 elements = no tag.

Comment: It would yeah, but a large % of rows falls outside of the regular structure also, in that they might contain extra information with more than the usual amount of delimiters. Some have less, but those rows are less of a concern at the moment.

Comment: makes sense to not split in that case. do you want to remove the rows that have extra info, or keep the rows but only till the five characters?

Comment: I want to remove the rows that have the extra info (the tag) - I'll be creating my own tags at a later stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're almost there in your substring query.

1. if you add 5 to the `len('I0')`, it will start the slice after the "Main ID"
2. then instead of taking only 5 characters (the last parameter of `substr`), take a large number

see example

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('afterchars', func.expr('substr(c1, instr(c1, "I0")+7, 100)')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +------------------------+----------+
# |c1                      |afterchars|
# +------------------------+----------+
# |IE01-236613-I073619-F021|-F021     |
# |IE01-236613-I073619-    |-         |
# |IE01-236613-I073619     |          |
# +------------------------+----------+
```

filter the `afterchars` column to keep rows with the length of zero

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('afterchars', func.expr('substr(c1, instr(c1, "I0")+7, 100)')). \
    filter(func.length('afterchars') == 0). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-------------------+----------+
# |c1                 |afterchars|
# +-------------------+----------+
# |IE01-236613-I073619|          |
# +-------------------+----------+
```

---

equivalent SQL query

```sql
select * from (
    select *, substr(c1, instr(c1, "I0")+7, 100) as afterchars
    from db.tbl)
where length(afterchars) = 0
```

Comment: Not following your last query sorry! I have the first bit of the example sussed though.

Comment: the second one is the same query with an additional filter -- `where length(afterchars) = 0` @regexted

Comment: Just back after lunch and tried this. It worked! Amazing! Now to remove the afterchars column, but that's not my problem :) thank you @samkart!!